# Spcial charter not print/echo in php mysql like 20 ° this type

Tags: php, mysql

when I am print/ echo type this 20 ° but this is not print ...this is converted like attached in the image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upfZI.png)

but in database is perfect show ...i show you the database please check image of database[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlVpm.png)

Comment: help us help you! please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML entity `&deg;` for the degree symbol

```
$Temperature = "22 &deg;";
echo $Temperature;
```

Comment: Add a semicolon after `deg`, like `deg;`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use charset in meta tag to support character

> **For HTML4:**

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">`

> **For HTML5:**

`<meta charset="UTF-8">`

> **What is Character Encoding?**

ASCII was the first character encoding standard (also called character set). ASCII defined 128 different alphanumeric characters that could be used on the internet: numbers (0-9), English letters (A-Z), and some special characters like ! $ + - ( ) @ < > .

ISO-8859-1 was the default character set for HTML 4. This character set also supported 256 different character codes.

ANSI (Windows-1252) was the original Windows character set. ANSI is identical to ISO-8859-1, except that ANSI has 32 extra characters.

Because ANSI and ISO-8859-1 were so limited, HTML 4 also supported UTF-8.

UTF-8 (Unicode) covers almost all of the characters and symbols in the world.

The default character encoding for HTML5 is UTF-8.

Comment: It gets even more complicated because MySQL stuffed up their original implementation of utf8